# How to calculate time with Tabulator.js

Tags: html, time, calculator, tabulator

I'm currently using Tabulator.js to get a table generated for my project. 
In my project I receive information from firebase and I load it to my table which is designed by TABULATOR.js ( http://tabulator.info ).

I know how to calculat normal value in my table. But I would like to calculate time. For example in row 1 I get 00:45 (45min) and row 2 I get 1:10 the result row should give me 1:55.

I not really familiar with web codding that's why I request your help.

My code :

```
var table = new Tabulator("#editor", {
        downloadConfig:{
            columnGroups:false, 
            rowGroups:false,
        },
        height:360, 
        data: arrayFlight,
        pagination:"local",
        resizableColumns: false,
        paginationSize:12,
        columnVertAlign:"center",
        columnHoriAlign:"center",
        columns:[ //I show you only the requested column
            {
            title:"SINGLE PILOT FLIGHT TIME",
                columns:[
                {title:"SE", field:"seTime", align:"center", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{inputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", outputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", invalidPlaceholder:"-"}, sorter:false, headerSort:false, width:95, bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcParams:{precision:2}},
                {title:"ME", field:"meTime", align:"center", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{inputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", outputFormat:"hh:mm:ss", invalidPlaceholder:"-"}, sorter:false, headerSort:false, width:95},
                ],
            },  
        ],
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the difference in time between the two columns to put in a third column?

Comment: No, I'm asking, how to get the sum between all the row in my table. I.E line 1 get 01:30 line 2 get 00:35 and line 3 get 00:25 I would like to add each time together and get the sum result, in this example : 03:30

Comment: how ahh with you now, how is the the time stored, is it a string with a value of "01:10" is m:s or h:m:s?

Comment: It is a string value with a value of "HH:MM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a custom column calculation for this, something like this:

```
//define custom calculation function
var timeSum = function(values, data, calcParams){
    //values - array of column values
    //data - all table data
    //calcParams - params passed from the column definition object

    var time = 0;

    values.forEach(function(value){
        if(value){
            //split time value into minutes and sum
            var values = value.split(":");

            time += parseInt(values[0]) * 60;
            time += parseInt(values[1]);
        }
    });

    //format sum as hour:minute
    return Math.floor(time/60) + ":" + time%60;
};
```

Then you can assign it in your column definition:

```
{title:"SE", field:"seTime", bottomCalc:timeSum}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not at home for now I'll try it sooner and give you my feed back ! I was'nt know that we could put a function into a bottomCalc Param :)

Comment: Great to hear! Happy Tabulating!